# Prophet forecasting saturating minimum not working

Tags: python, time-series, forecasting, facebook-prophet

I have a Solar radiation time series data for 2 years, It is half hourly(every 30 mins) and it has a daily and yearly seasonality with no trend. All the input y values are above 0 and below 1000. Over the course of the day, from midnight till morning the values are 0 and during the day till evening it has positive values with peak in the afternoon and values are 0 in the night.

I intially tried simple model and in the forecasting I see negative values popping up(that were supposed to be 0). After reading through the prophet documentation and other posts here , I tried saturating minimum option, using logistic model with floor set to 0 and cap to 1000, but still I get negative values in the prediction(that was supposed to be 0).

```
future = m.make_future_dataframe( periods=48, freq='30min')
future['floor']=0
future['cap']=1000
df_solar['cap']=1000
m = Prophet(growth='logistic', weekly_seasonality=False)
forecast = m.fit(df_solar).predict(future)
```

So, is the staturating minimum not working ? How can I get to predict correctly with out negative values where the values should be 0 ? Any help, appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to plot the components of the model:

```
m.plot_components(forecast)
```

With the logistic growth model, Prophet is setting a floor/cap saturation point to the trend component. But it is possible that other components (i.e., the extra regressors) are driving your predictions into a negative number. If you require a hard stop in 0 and 1000, instead you should consider a Censored Regression (a.k.a. Tobit regression). You can see an example using PyMC [here](https://www.pymc.io/projects/examples/en/latest/generalized_linear_models/GLM-truncated-censored-regression.html) or perhaps do the estimation using Stan.